# Magento Event for change of interface locale (or language locale)

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, localisation, locale, interface

Is there any **event dispatched** when you change the **interface locale** ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an event dispatched when the admin interface locale is changed you can use `controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_index_changeLocale` and you can use the following code to get the new locale:

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('locale');
```